# Set Column Property for a column in a revision table

Tags: vb.net, api, solidworks

I am trying to set column property for a column called "description". I tried using `IRevisionTableAnnotation` and `TableAnnotation` to identify the table and neither of them have a command that lets me set the column property.

`IRevisionTableAnnotation` does let me set a custom property through `SetColumnCustomProperty`, but i want to set the column property given by default and not use custom column properties.

Is there any way I can assign the column properties available by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setcolumntype2` attribute for `TableAnnotation` will let you set the default properties for the table (Parameter to be entered in integer).